# How to synchronize with Transport in JavaMail?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jakarta-mail

I have an application that should work like this:

1. Open a connection with a Transport provider.
2. Send a bunch of Messages as quickly as possible.
3. Close connection with Transport provider.

What I've found is that my application moves too fast for the Transport thread. I end up missing messages, because I move on to the next message before the Transport thread is finished with the one before it. To (temporarily) solve this problem, I have resorted to putting a 2-second pause between the launch of one message, and the creation of the next. But this is unacceptable! What I want is some sort of semaphore that I can wait on to determine when the Transport thread is completely done with a message (i.e., I want synchronous operation).

Does anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Transport **is** synchronous.

What do you mean you're "missing messages"?  Do you mean that, even though the Transport says the message has been sent (with no exceptions), the message never arrives at the destination?  That likely indicates a bug in your mail server.

You might want to try turning on Session debugging as described in the JavaMail FAQ to see if there's anything in the conversation with the mail server that would indicate why it's not working as you expect.

Comment: Wow. I must be doing this completely wrong. From the trace I discovered that Transport is connecting to the server for each email, sending the message, and then disconnecting. Is there an example of code that does what I want (see description above)?

Comment: Yup, in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#rptsend).

Comment: Bill Shannon: I tried the session.setDebug(true), and got a lot of useful info. It really is connecting each and every time for every message (very slow). I'm reusing the Session object I created and the Message object too. I've looked at all the examples, but they only show sending one message. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you make [this mistake](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#send)?

Comment: No. I did not. I use Transport.send(msg).

Comment: Exactly, you're using Transport.send instead of Transport.sendMessage.  Please read both of those FAQ entries again, and read more carefully.